# Regarding Current date comparision in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing the below specified query which has no error but doesn't fetch me the correct record which matches current date of server, on other part it shows me old records

My Mysql Query:

```
select news_title,
    full_url,
    source_site,
    date_added,
    `category`
from tbl_urlLog
where category like '%enter%'
    or category like '%hollywood%'
    or category like '%bollywood%'
    or category like '%movies%'
    or category like '%film%'
    and date (`date_added`) = date (CURDATE())
group by `source_site`
order by `date_added` desc LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Actually you need to enclose all those `or` statements within parenthesis and also using those `date` function within where conditions make your query `non-sargable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to group together all the `OR`s using parentheses. Also, `curdate()` already is date no need to call `date()` on it.

```
select news_title,
    full_url,
    source_site,
    date_added,
    `category`
from tbl_urlLog
where (
        category like '%enter%'
        or category like '%hollywood%'
        or category like '%bollywood%'
        or category like '%movies%'
        or category like '%film%'
        )
    and date (`date_added`) = CURDATE()
group by `source_site`
order by `date_added` desc LIMIT 3
```